# Need help on PL/SQL database trigger

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have a DB trigger `before insert on emp` table. I would like to add `sal, comm from emp_test` table and want to use those value as a default in the `emp` table, by trigger. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: How do those tables look like (we need their description). What is stored in EMP_TEST? A single row? Many rows (perhaps one per employee)? How are they distinguished? Why don't you create a DEFAULT value for those EMP columns?

Answer (score 0):

Until you provide answers to questions I posted in a comment, here's how you might do it. See if you can adjust it.

EMP_TEST table contains only one row (which is kind of *stupid*; you'd rather use DEFAULT value for those columns in the EMP table).

```
SQL> create table emp_test (sal number, comm number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into emp_test (sal, comm) values (3000, 100);

1 row created.
```

Trigger takes SAL and COMM values if they are provided; otherwise, it takes values from the EMP_TEST table.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_emp
  2    before insert on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select nvl(:new.sal, t.sal),
  6           nvl(:new.comm, t.comm)
  7     into :new.sal,
  8          :new.comm
  9     from emp_test t;
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: I didn't provide SAL value (so trigger will insert EMP_TEST one), but I did provide COMM:

```
SQL> insert into emp (empno, ename, deptno, sal, comm)
  2    values (1, 'Littlefoot', 40, null, 50);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from emp where empno = 1;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Littlefoot                                     3000         50         40

SQL>
```